# Android Studio opened classes not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been struggling for this minor thing in Android Studio for few hours. I am not sure if it's a bug or a new feature in **Android studio 2.3.3**.

I can't see the classes that i have opened. They were appearing fine before,I didn't update the studio or did any other thing intentionally.

**Expected Result:**
[image]

**Current Screen:**
[image]

P.S: The second screen shot is from linux as i am currently working on linux. It was working fine before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set tab visibility none, so you can change visibility by 
press

> Ctrl + Shift + A

then write **tabs placements** and then you find **tabs placements top** is **off** so press to **On**.
You can see the tabs.;)

Comment: Welcome men ; )

Answer (score 2):

this is the simple way to do that
go to

**Window -> Editor Tabs -> Tabs placement  -> set to Top**